# AZ IoTEdge Connect-eFlowVM "Connection timed out during banner exchange"

Tags: powershell, azure-iot-edge

after successfull setup of an IoTEdge-Device on MS Server 2022 including some own modules (everything's working fine), restart due to memeory increase,
it's not possible to connect to the VM from Powershell.
The Modules are working fine, reachable via their UI,
CPU-Load and Memory of VM seen on Hyper-V-Manager is ok.
Only the connection to the eFlow-VM with SSH (Connect-eFlowVM) is not working.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Connect-EflowVm
Connection timed out during banner exchange

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-EflowVmAddr

[10/16/2023 08:54:15] Querying IP and MAC addresses from virtual machine (LP-VM-JNW-EFLOW)

- Virtual machine MAC: 00:15:5d:e1:6e:03
- Failed to acquire IP address for virtual machine

Hyper-V-Manager shows the correct address (172.20.0.2)

Any hints how to check why connect stucks?

Tried to connect with Win-SCP using the private key from
C:\ProgramData\Azure IoT Edge\protected.sshkey
but did not work
Any hint how to get credentiols for iotedge-user?

tried to connect into eFlowVM
and want to login successfull

Comment: Hope this reference [1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/virtual-machines/windows/connect-ssh.md) ,                               [2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-edge/how-to-configure-iot-edge-for-linux-on-windows-networking.md)                                                 [3](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-edge/troubleshoot-iot-edge-for-linux-on-windows-common-errors.md) helps

Answer (score 0):

In the event of a failure connecting to Eflow via the Connect-EFlowVm, you can get to the console of the machine in an alternative manner. This will let you look around to see what might have caused your problem.

From an administrator PowerShell prompt enter:

```
hcsdiag list
```

This will output a list of VMs. For example"

```
c5ab8b64-e9fd-11ed-8337-902e162e73cd
    VM,                         Running, C5AB8B64-E9FD-11ED-8337-902E162E73CD, wssdagent
```

Find the GUID for the wssdagent enter the command

```
hcsdiag console [the GUID you found above]
```

This will give you a console on the VM. The first thing I recommend you look at is the disk space. If you did not set up your docker logs to rotate, the Eflow machine will run out of disk space and will cause exactly the behavior you are seeing.